# The isomorphism $\Gamma(X \times G, p^*L) \cong \mathbb{C}[G] \otimes \Gamma(X, p^*(L))$ on ginzburg page 240

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $L$ be a line bundle over $X$ and let there be a projection $p : X \times G \to X$, where $X$ is projective and $G$ is an algebraic group.  I understand the isomorphism given above.

I have two questions.
1)Ginzburg refers me to the whole of Hartshorne chapter 3(on Cohomology) to show this equality when $L$ is a sheaf over $X$.  Where can I find it?(Even better why is it true?)

2)This is just a remark:  I know why this is true when $L$ is a line bundle:

I am not going to use at all that $G$ is a group.  We have that the sequence of maps $X \to X \times G \xrightarrow{p} X$ which is the identity and $G \to X \times G \xrightarrow{p} X$ which is null.  Thus given a section $s \in $ $\Gamma(X \times G, p^*L)$ one can pull $s$ back to a section of $\Gamma(G,\epsilon)=\mathbb{C}[G]$ and one can also pull $s$ back to get a section of $\Gamma(X,L)$.  Hence one gets a map from $\Gamma(X, p^*(L)) \to \mathbb{C}[G] \otimes \Gamma(X,L)$.

My motivation is that I want to find a map from $H^i(X, p^*(L)) \to \mathbb{C}[G] \otimes H^i(X,L)$.